# no type named asio in namespace boost

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, asio

I am attempting to write an asynchronous TCP server using `boost::asio`.
The `using Tcp = boost::asio::ip::tcp` directive is working correctly. However if I define

`using Asio = boost::asio` it doesn't seem to work. I get the error `no type named asio in namespace boost`. why is that?

Why is that?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/optional.hpp>

using namespace  std;

using Tcp = boost::asio::ip::tcp;

class session{
public:
    session(Tcp::socket &&socket)
        : m_socket(std::move(socket))
    {

    }

    void async_read(){

    }
private:
    Tcp::socket  m_socket;
    boost::asio::streambuf m_streambuf;

};



class server{

public:
    server(boost::asio::io_context &io_context, std::uint16_t port)
    : io_context(io_context)
    , m_acceptor(io_context, Tcp::endpoint(Tcp::v4(), port))
    {

    }

    void async_accept() {

    }


private:
    boost::asio::io_context& io_context;
    Tcp::acceptor m_acceptor;
    boost::optional<Tcp::socket>  m_socket;
};






int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do this:

```
namespace asio = boost::asio;
```

`using foo =` is for types, and namespaces are not types.

Ref: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace_alias